# $C=\{y:y=\lambda(x− \bar{x}), \lambda \geq 0, x \in S\}$ is convex if $S$ is convex.

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

From  Bazaraa, Sherali, and Shetty's Nonlinear Programming. Probem 2.16:

Let $S$ be a non-empty set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\bar{x} \in S$. Consider the set $C=\{y:y=\lambda(x− \bar{x}), \lambda \geq 0, x \in S\}$

(a)  Show that $C$ is a cone and interpret it geometrically.

(b)  Show that $C$ is convex if $S$ is convex.

(c)  Suppose that $S$ is closed. Is it necessarily true that $C$ is closed? If not, under what conditions would $C$ be closed?

I have (a) fine.

I'm getting caught with (b). I've tried directly showing that if:
$y_1, y_2 \in C \implies \lambda_1(x_1 - \bar{x}_1), \lambda_2(x_2 - \bar{x}_2) \in C$, then:
$\lambda_3[\lambda_1(x_1 - \bar{x}_1)]+(1-\lambda_3)[\lambda_2(x_2 - \bar{x}_2)]$ directly rearranges to $\lambda[\bar{\lambda}x_1+(1-\bar{\lambda})\bar{x}_1-\hat{\lambda}x_2-(1-\hat{\lambda})\bar{x}_2]$ with arbitrary lambdas.

Can't seem to make that work. I also tried saying that $x,\bar{x} \in S \implies (x-\bar{x}) \in S \implies \lambda(x-\bar{x}) +(1-\lambda)(x-\bar{x}) \in S$ and just multiplying by $\lambda$. That worked, but I feel like it relies on $S$ being closed under addition, and I don't know if that holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y_1=\lambda_1(x_1-\bar x)\in C$ and $y_2=\lambda_2(x_2-\bar x)\in C$ where $\lambda _1,\lambda _2>0$ and $x_1,x_2\in S$. Therefore for any $0<\lambda <1$ $$
\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda)y_2=\lambda \lambda_1x_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2x_2-[\lambda \lambda_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2]\bar x
$$
We know that since $\bar x\in S$ and $S$ is convex, then ${\lambda \lambda_1x_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2x_2\over \lambda \lambda_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2}\in S$. Hence 
${\lambda \lambda_1x_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2x_2\over \lambda \lambda_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2}-\bar x\in C$  and since $C$ is a cone, ${\lambda \lambda_1x_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2x_2}-[{\lambda \lambda_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2}]\bar x\in C$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure I'm following why $\bar{x} \in S$ and $S$ convex yield $\frac{\lambda\lambda_1x_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2x_2}{\lambda\lambda_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2} \in S$.

Comment: Well, $\bar x$ is in $S$ by assumption. Also we have concluded $x_1,x_2\in S$ (because C is constructed so). Since $S$ is convex, we have $\theta x_1+(1-\theta)x_2\in S$ for $0<\theta<1$. Now substitute $$\theta={\lambda\lambda_1\over \lambda\lambda_1+(1-\lambda)\lambda_2}$$

Comment: I follow, thank you!

Comment: Wish you luck!.